# How can I close a port and also kill all active connections ASAP?

Tags: python, proxy, twisted

I have a server running which spawns new TCP ports implementing the portforward proxy.  I need to be able to remove a port and disconnect all clients ASAP.

```
factory = ProxyFactory(host, port)
port = reactor.listenTCP(0, factory)
```

then later

```
port.loseConnection()
```

This will close the port, but active connections are not closed!  How can I close the port and kill all connections?

Comment: If calling `loseConnection` on a port shuts it down, it's an accident of the implementation.  The method you're looking for is `stopListening`.  This doesn't answer your question but it does point out a possible problem with other code you have.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using the following code.  **RPC** is the manager server to add new proxies, and **ProxyClient** overrides *twisted.protocols.portforward.ProxyClient*

Basically, I had to keep track of clients on my own and call **abortConnection** when I wanted to kill their transports.

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, error
from twisted.web import xmlrpc, server
from twisted.python import log, failure
import socket

class RPC(xmlrpc.XMLRPC):
    proxies = {} # (host, port): tcp.Port()
    clients = [] # list of active client transports

    def __get(self, host, port):
        if (host, port) in self.proxies.keys():
            return self.proxies.get((host, port))
        return self.__new(host, port)

    def __new(self, host, port):
        factory = ProxyFactory(host, port)
        tcp_port = reactor.listenTCP(0, factory)
        self.proxies[(host, port)] = tcp_port
        return tcp_port

    def xmlrpc_get(self, host, port):
        log.msg('get {}'.format(host, port))
        port = self.__get(host, port)
        return port.getHost().port

    def xmlrpc_kill(self, host, port):
        log.msg('kill {}'.format(host, port))
        tcp_port = self.proxies.pop((host, port), None)
        if not tcp_port:
            return False
        tcp_port.loseConnection() # don't listen anymore
        try:
            ip = socket.gethostbyname(host)
        except:
            return False
        for client in list(self.clients):
            # kill connections now because we're anxious
            peer = client.getPeer()
            if (ip, port) == (peer.host, peer.port):
                log.msg('abort {}'.format(client))
                client.abortConnection()
                self.clients.remove(client)
        return True


class ProxyClient(Proxy):
    def connectionMade(self):
        RPC.clients.append(self.transport)
        self.peer.setPeer(self)

        # Wire this and the peer transport together to enable
        # flow control (this stops connections from filling
        # this proxy memory when one side produces data at a
        # higher rate than the other can consume).
        self.transport.registerProducer(self.peer.transport, True)
        self.peer.transport.registerProducer(self.transport, True)

        # We're connected, everybody can read to their hearts content.
        self.peer.transport.resumeProducing()

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.transport in RPC.clients:
            RPC.clients.remove(self.transport)
```